# Discord Table of Contents

Tags: hyperlink, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to create a how-to on my discord server with a table of contents.

I know how to use an embed to get named links, but I can't figure out how to make those links point to other specific locations within the channel. I found [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/b7zx3h/i_made_an_embed_based_table_of_contents_system/) that looks like what I want, but there is no description about how it was accomplished. They need to link back and forth, so I can't just post the first message and then copy a link to that.

Comment: You can use message links. (Example: (https://discord.com/channels/673244755064258560/678970502852902953/786488956953821195)

Comment: First off - I don't want to use those long ugly leaks.

Secondly, I can't do that (I even mentioned it above) because I need to be able to do cross links. So page 1 needs to be able to go to page 2 and vice versa.

Comment: You can turn it into an [Hyperlink](https://discord.com/channels/673244755064258560/678970502852902953/786488956953821195). `[Title](Link)`.

Comment: What do you mean you can't do that? That approach is indeed what the example in the post you linked to is using, when paired with the hyperlink method that @Jakye mentioned. They simply posted all of the messages, and then had their bot go back and edit in the links to each of the messages. There are many ways you could go about doing so, you could even create a command in your bot that allows you to manually edit the embeds.

Comment: That's what I don't know how to do. I can post a new embed message, but I don't know how to make a bot go back and edit it's post, or to make it possible to manually edit it.

The hyperlink method doesn't work in discord directly - only in an embed message, so I have to do it this way.